# Mutiny async update

Tags: asynchronous, quarkus, mutiny

I am trying to update a document asynchronously without need to worry:

```
persistenceManager.updateElement(datastore, filterParams, fieldsToUpdate)
throw new MyException(ErrorCodes.GONE, errMsg);
```

updateElement returns a Uni<Integer>. Throwing Exception triggers an aspect (interceptor) to finalize metrics and to log errors in a standard way.

updateElement never updates the element. I tried to await() but Vertx complains the call is blocking. I tried onItem().failWith() no luck it does not interrupt the normal flow. I tried   subscribe(), onItem().invoke(x->log...).
How can I be sure at least the update is sent to database before throwing exception and end the call?
It seems the call ends always before the update is even tried.

Thanks

Comment: Is the code calling `persistenceManager.updateElement` reactive?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to throw an exception asynchronously, you need to create a failed item:

```
return persistenceManager
    .updateElement(datastore, filterParams, fieldsToUpdate)
    .chain( () -> Uni.createFrom().failure(new MyException(ErrorCodes.GONE, errMsg)) );
```

Or, throw the exception in a following uni:

```
return persistenceManager
    .updateElement(datastore, filterParams, fieldsToUpdate)
    .invoke( () -> throw new MyException(ErrorCodes.GONE, errMsg) );
```

Or, you can use `.failWith`:

```
return persistenceManager
    .updateElement(datastore, filterParams, fieldsToUpdate)
    .failWith( () -> throw new MyException(ErrorCodes.GONE, errMsg) );
```

Note that in all these functions, I've used the form `() -> ...`. But if you need the item returned by `updateElement`, this will also work:
`item -> ...`.

Comment: Thanks, you really need a "forma mentis" for async programming. I did something equivalent:

`return persistenceManager.updateElement(datastore(), filterParams, fieldsToUpdate).map(x->new PojoReturnType()).onItem().failWith(x->new MyException(ErrorCodes.GONE, errMsg));`

Map thing to match returned type of the method, that I guess does not matter.
So many ways and at the end they all make sense.

Comment: Ah, that works too. I will add it to my answer for posterity

Comment: I guess the point is that you need to chain something that fails